# SQL server Impersonation in RIA services

Tags: sql-server, security, entity-framework, ria, silverlight-5.0

I have deployed a RIA application with silverlight 5. I'm using the entity framework to manage data of a SQL Server 2008 R2.

The authentication mode is by Forms and the user is identified by the AD.

Everythings works fine. I can load, insert or modify data but the problem comes with the impersonation.

I checked the SQL Server profile and I see that the LoginName is NT AUTHORITY\Network service. This means that the ASP impersonation is not working. Oviously I have enabled the ASP impersonation in the IIS and the we.config file .

Why is this happening?

Comment: A clue: With <authentication mode="Windows" /> the Impersonation works fine. Looks like the initial page needs Anonimous Authetication so the user can see the page without entering a user and password, and it seems that WCF preserves the Anonimous Authetication even after the login

Comment: I temporally execute the WCF under a given user with enough permisions. Not perfect, but from now I'll do it work.